# Declare an array of Int in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

How can I declare an array of integers inside `RLMObject`?

Like :

```
dynamic var key:[Int]?
```

Gives the following error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''NSArray' is not supported as an RLMObject property. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, RLMArray, or subclasses of RLMObject. See https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html for more information.'
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Lists of primitives are not supported yet unfortunately. There is issue [#1120](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1120) to track adding support for that. You'll find there some ideas how you can workaround that currently.

The easiest workaround is create a object to hold int values. Then the model to have a List of the object.

```
class Foo: Object {
    let integerList = List<IntObject>() // Workaround
}

class IntObject: Object {
    dynamic var value = 0
}
```

Comment: This is just incredible that Realm doesn't support such a simple thing.

Comment: Is the support still not implemented?

Comment: Not yet. But Realm core team working hard now. It will be supported soon.

Comment: Looks like it is now supported, as of v3.0.0-beta.4 https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.4

Comment: No, it's not. I'm using v3.0.2. It still can't store List<Int> to database.

Comment: @KimiChiu `List<Int>` should work from v3.0 https://realm.io/blog/realm-cocoa-reaches-3-0/  Probably you're something wrong.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi You're right. It's working. I put a wrong value to the where clause.

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately arrays of primitive types are now supported in Realm 3.0 and above. (Oct 31 2017)

> You can now store primitive types or their nullable counterparts (more specifically: booleans, integer and floating-point number types, strings, dates, and data) directly within RLMArrays or Lists. If you want to define a list of such primitive values you no longer need to define cumbersome single-field wrapper objects. Instead, you can just store the primitive values themselves!

```
class MyObject : Object {
    @objc dynamic var myString: String = ""
    let myIntArray = List<Int>()
}
```

Source: https://realm.io/blog/realm-cocoa-reaches-3-0/

Comment: For what it's worth, if you choose to use a `List` of Primitives like this, you won't be able to filter `Results` using the `@count` predicate style as it's not supported on `List`s of Primitives . That said, wrapping them in Realm objects has it's own downsides...
From https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/filter-data/:
"Evaluates to the number of objects in the given collection. This is currently only supported on to-many relationship collections and not on lists of primitives. In order to use `@count` on a list of primitives, consider wrapping the primitives in a Realm object."

Answer (score 5):

The accepted offer is very costly in term of memory.
You might get a List of very big "n" of objects.

It's not a matter of right and wrong but I think it's good to write here a different workaround.

Another approach:
I decided to use a single string to represent an Int array.

In my Realm class I defined a variable:

```
dynamic var arrInt: String? = nil
```

And use it very easily:

```
let arrToSave = [0, 1, 33, 12232, 394]
<MY_CUSTOM_REALM_CLASS>.arrInt = arrToSave.map { String(describing: $0) }.joined(separator: ",")
```

And the way back:

```
let strFetched = <MY_CUSTOM_REALM_CLASS>.arrInt 
let intArray = strFetched.components(separatedBy: ",").flatMap { Int($0) }
```

Will be happy to hear your feedback, as I think this approach is better.

Comment: Why the down vote? I presented this answer as a proposal that worked for me, if you don't like this solution, please share your thoughts, don't just down vote.

Comment: Using `description` is a very, very bad idea. Use this: to: `let stringOfArray = arrToSave.map { String(describing: $0) }.joined(separator: ",")`. From:  `let intArray = stringOfArray.components(separatedBy: ",").flatMap { Int($0) }`

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you have to use `RLMArray` - or rather it's swift equivalent `List`.

See: [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships)